Find an open and connected set around zero for which the equality holds.
Show that there exists an open and connected neighborhood around
$0$ where the following identity holds for every branch of the logarithm
$$\log(1 + e^z) - \log (1 + e^{-z}) = z$$
I need help with the strategy. For example, which theorems would be useful to keep in mind?
If $\log$ is a branch of logarithm,
$$e^{\log\bigg(\dfrac{1 + e^z}{1 + e^{-z}}\bigg)} = \dfrac{1 + e^z}{1 + e^{-z}}$$
and the firts equation is valid if
$$e^z = \dfrac{1 + e^z}{1 + e^{-z}} \Longleftrightarrow e^z(1 + e^{-z}) = 1 + e^z$$
which occurs always?
Are there sufficient conditions to ensure that there exists a branch of the logarithm in an open and connected set? Is it sufficient to show that there exists a branch in an open and connected set?

You're dividing by zero if $1 + e^{-z} = 0$.
